# Microsoft Access 2007 - Allow only certain values in attribute

Tags: database, validation, format, prefix, relational

I am incredibly new to Microsoft Access, and would really appreciate some help with this.
I am creating a database for a fictional estate agency, that deals with the selling of local property. The property is submitted into it's own relation, with an identifier and it's details. One of these details is it's postcode.
As the "company" deals exclusively with local properties, I need to find a way to only accept one of three values for the postcode:
AA1***
AA2***
AA3***
The asterisks are random values - I am not too concerned about validating the input against existing postcodes, merely wishing to only accept postcodes beginning with one of those three values.

A point in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In desin-mode of the table got to the properties of the field (in the lower part of the screen) - there you can set this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me - I didn't notice that there. However, all it's done is raised a hundred new questions. How does it work? What kind of functions/commands should I be looking out for? Thanks.

Comment: as I am using german Access, I am not quite sure about the correct wording. In a text field it is the 6th properties counting from top, and says something like "range allowed" or "Validation rule". There you put "like "AA1???" or like "AA2???" or like "AA3???". The question mark replaces one character, whereas if you put a * the user can insert as many characters as he likes